# Passing the values of mysql_fetch_array to an Array()?

Tags: php

this is my code:

```
$scontain = "SELECT id FROM voting";
$qcontain = mysql_query($scontain);

$r_idarray = array();
while ($rcontain = mysql_fetch_array($qcontain))
{
    $r_idarray[] = $rcontain['id'];
    //let's say there are 5 names here//
}

echo $r_idarray;
```

I was trying to get the whole content of my table 'voting'. Inside the while loop it successfully prints out the whole content of the table which is under the column 'id' but when I tried to echo it outside the while loop it prints 'Array'? Can anyone knows how to solve this. Thank you in advance...

Comment: Can you rewrite your code without "enter code here" ? Too unreadable

Comment: Please rewrite your code clear so we can help you.

Comment: `print_r` recursively prints an array showing all keys and values. `echo` does not, and is intended for scalar values.

Comment: Another thing, my real objective was to use $r_idarray; how do I do that, do I still need to declare a variable and use print_r($r_idarray); like, 

$a = print_r($r_idarray);

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

To print the array you can do:

```
print_r($r_idarray);
```

instead of

```
echo $r_idarray;
```

Comment: Another thing, my real objective was to use the values inside $r_idarray; to use it for comparison in my If else, how do I do that, do I still need to declare a variable and use print_r($r_idarray); like, $a = print_r($r_idarray); Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use print_r($r_idarray) .

echo is used for printing strings.

use print_r for printing arrays.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) or [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) for printing the `array`

Replace:

```
echo $r_idarray;
```

With:

```
print_r($r_idarray);
```

Or:

```
var_dump($r_idarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display whole content

```
SELECT id FROM voting
```

To

```
SELECT * FROM voting
```

And after that you can use `print_r($r_idarray);`

Answer (score 0):

You can't "echo" an array, you can only "echo" a string. Of course you will see 'Array'.
In order to print out the contents of an array, you either have to iterate through it's contents, or do a "var_dump($array)".

```
while($val in $array){
  echo $val;
}
```

or:

```
print_r($array);
```

or:

```
var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing youe query should be like this to select all columns

```
$scontain = "SELECT * FROM voting";
```

You only have to do this

```
$i=0;
while ($rcontain = mysql_fetch_array($qcontain))
{
    $r_idarray[$i] = $rcontain;
    $i++;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($r_idarray);
```

And if you need particular columns from result

```
$i=0;
while ($rcontain = mysql_fetch_array($qcontain))
{
    $r_idarray[$i]['id'] = $rcontain['id'];
    $r_idarray[$i]['column1'] = $rcontain['column1'];
    $r_idarray[$i]['column2'] = $rcontain['column2'];
    $r_idarray[$i]['column3'] = $rcontain['column3'];
    $i++;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($r_idarray);
```